# is it possible to use same keyhash for all my apk version?

Tags: android

I have uploaded one application in android market , while installing in my phone its ask for keyhash .so i newly inserted my keyhash .(which is in my phone)
Now i am released next version in android market , then now also it asks for keyhash.

Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "8Ioc4p/jMXoU9Lezug4nzmZfFUg" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers

1)is it possible way to use same keyhash for all my apk version.
2)if i used different keyhash for every version,facebook configuration  will affect or not.

Comment: If you mean the key that you use to sign application while releasing then I think you can use the same keyhash for all applications. But all applications should have different package names except in the case where you are going to have multiple apks for same application to target specific devices. I am not sure how facebook configuration will get affected if you do this.

Comment: Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "8Ioc4p/jMXoU9Lezug4nzmZfFUg" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers                                         i had taken this keyhash from my mobile and i inserted into my facebook account but now for new version from the same device its shows mismatch keyhash . how to have same keyhash for all versions

Comment: for every build , its generating different keyhash. even though i am using sam keystore and same alias name and same package name.

Comment: Now , i have found  out my mistake .I had used different alias name for my keystore.

Comment: Put your answer and accept it. It may help others.